# BDC Security Issues

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, bdc

We are planning to use BDC to read and probably write to a SQL Server content database on external server. I have heard that there are many security issues that you may run into or should be aware of before setting up BDC.

has anyone faced or knows any security issues with BDC. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives a good overview of BDC

http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/administration/everything-you-need-to-know-about-bdc-part-1-of-8

Part 8 shows how to use the BDC to write back data - though its a rarely used feature in 2007. There are some more examples here

http://bilbroblog.com/sharepoint/yes-virginia-you-can-write-through-the-bdc/

http://www.cleverworkarounds.com/2009/06/04/new-book-preview-sharepoint-2007-developers-guide-to-the-business-data-catalog/

http://www.lightningtools.com/bdc-meta-man/business-data-catalog-write-back.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In MOSS2007, the BDC is read only, not write.

Comment: Not quite true - see links in my reply.